# java gui testing

Tags: java, junit4

in the java test I have :

```
package Tester.GUI.api
public class Test1{-----}
```

in the ".bat" :

```
<path to java> -classpath<all jar defined in the classpath separated by ";"> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.GUI.api.Test1
```

when I launch th ".bat" I have the following :

```
JUnit version 4.6
Could not find class: Tester.GUI.api.Test1
Time: 0,203

OK (0 tests)
```

I have verified jar files , typo but not found the cause
someone could help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-classpath` option needs to take a set of directies and/or jar files. Currently those are missing, so your main class (`JUnitCore`) is being used as the classpath, and `Test1` used as the main class. I'm guessing you want `JUnitCore` as the main class and `Test1` as the argument.

Try something like this (substituting the actual names of the jars you're using for jar-file1, jar-file2):

```
java -classpath <jar-file1.jar>;<jar-file2.jar> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.GUI.api.Test1
```

**Edit:**
Assuming jar files are specified correctly, the error message indicates that the `Test1` class isn't on the classpath. If you're using an IDE, you need to find the output directory for compilation (for example, in Eclipse it is `<project>/bin` by default). Within this directory you will find other directories with the structure `Tester/GUI/api`. A file called `Test1.class` will be in the `api` directory. It is this output directory that needs to be added to the classpath (that is, the one above the `Tester/GUI/api` structure).

Comment: I have not mentionned the jar files because I have many jar, it is already specified in the -classpath , shuld I add something in the .classpath file in the src? add java test class name?

Comment: You may also be able to omit the `-classpath` option entirely if your system is already set up to include all of the needed jar files in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.  In that case, your command would just be `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.GUI.api.Test1`.

Comment: @laura: .classpath (you're using Eclipse or some other IDE?) will have no effect from a .bat file. It sounds purely like your `Test1` class isn't being found on the classpath. @Joe's suggestions should help you track it down (for example, add `;bin/` to your classpath list if you're using, say, Eclipse with the default output folder of `bin`). Basically, you want to add the folder that your test classes are being compiled to.

Comment: You bring up a good point: The important thing is where the complied .class files are, not where the .java source files are.  If you're using an IDE (as the mention of ".classpath" would suggest), then those won't be the same by default.

I've already edited my answer accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It says that the class that it cannot find is `Tester.GUI.api.Test1`.  What directory are you running the test from, and what directory is your `Test1` code in?

If you set the `-classpath` variable, you may also need to include the current directory in your classpath.  So, if your original command was

```
java -classpath C:\foo.jar;D:\bar1\bar2.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.GUI.api.Test1
```

you could add the current directory to your classpath by adding `;.` to the end of your `-classpath` option like this:

```
java -classpath C:\foo.jar;D:\bar1\bar2.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.GUI.api.Test1
```

This will work as long as the `Test1` class is in the `Tester\GUI\api` directory under the current directory.

The tricky thing with setting the classpath in Java is that you don't want to give the directory where your actual .java files are, but instead you want to give the directory under which you can find the directories that are named for the packages in your code.

For example, if I compiled a class `Foo` in a package `bar.baz`, then I should have a file named `Foo.class` in a directory named `baz` inside another directory named `bar`.  If I want to include `Foo` in my classpath, and if `Foo.class` is located at
`C:\Users\Joe\Code\bar\baz\Foo.class`, then I have to either run

```
java -classpath C:\Users\Joe\Code [main class goes here]
```

or else I have to change my directory to `C:\Users\Joe\Code` and run

```
java -classpath . [main class goes here]
```

Comment: I do not understand :
should I add to class path :
-java -classpath C:\foo.jar;C:\api\Test1;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.GUI.api.Test1

Comment: I can give a much more precise answer if you could answer these two questions:  1. In what directory is your `.bat` file being run?  2. In what directory is `Test1.class`?

If you don't know where `Test1.class` is, then I still might be able to help if you could tell me where `Test1.java` is and how you compiled `Test1.java`.  For example, did you use an IDE like Eclipse to compile `Test1`, or did you use the `javac` command in a batch file or at the command prompt?